# TypeScript and React: Pass component in props and return it from a function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, react-props, typescript-types

I'm writing a Form component with React and TypeScript. I use Formik for the form logic. I want to pass the `<Form />` component a specific form as a prop and render it. Here is what I tried:

```
import { Formik, FormikProps } from "formik";
import React, { PureComponent, ReactNode } from "react";

export interface Props {
  component: ReactNode; // TODO: Change to one of LoginForm or RegisterForm.
  handleSubmit(): void;
}

export class Form extends PureComponent<Props> {
  renderForm = (formikProps: FormikProps<any>): ReactNode => {
    const { component: FormComponent } = this.props;
    return <FormComponent {...formikProps} />;
  };

  render() {
    const { handleSubmit } = this.props;
    return <Formik render={this.renderForm} />;
  }
}

export default Form;
```

The problem is that the line where I return the `<FormComponent />` throws the error:

```
[ts] JSX element type 'FormComponent' does not have any construct or call signatures.
```

`renderForm` has to return a ReactNode, so I can't change `ReactNode` to `ComponentType` (the latter would resolve the JSX error).

How would one do this in TypeScript?

**Edit**
So I got it working by doing this (thanks to [estus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3731501/estus)):

```
import { Formik, FormikProps } from "formik";
import React, { PureComponent, ReactElement } from "react";

export interface Props {
  component: React.ComponentType<any>; // TODO: Change to one of LoginForm or RegisterForm.
  handleSubmit(): void;
}

export class Form extends PureComponent<Props> {
  renderForm = (formikProps: FormikProps<any>): ReactElement<any> => {
    const { component: FormComponent } = this.props;
    return <FormComponent {...formikProps} />;
  };

  render() {
    const { handleSubmit } = this.props;
    return <Formik render={this.renderForm} />;
  }
}

export default Form;
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`ReactNode` is React *element* type, while `component` prop is expected to be React *component*.

It likely should be:

```
export interface Props {
  component: React.ComponentType;
  handleSubmit(): void;
}
```

> renderForm has to return a ReactNode, so I can't change ReactNode to ComponentType (the latter would resolve the JSX error).

`component` prop and `renderForm` return type aren't connected. The former is a component and the latter is an element.

Comment: Hi estus, thank you for helping me again I made an edit to the post after your answer, I was just wondering if that is what you meant with your answer?